# Как записать результат в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо записать результат в файл

```
import requests
import json
f=open(r'D:\Arcgis\M.txt','w')
r = requests.get('https://5ka.ru/api/stores/?bbox=10.0000,10.0000,100.0000,100.0000')
if r.status_code == 200:
    j = json.loads(r.text[9:-2]) # обрезаем лишнее обрамление у JSON
    for feature in j['data']['features']:
        f.write(feature['geometry']['coordinates'],feature['properties']['address']+'\n')
    f.close()
```

выдаёт ошибку
`f.write(feature['geometry']['coordinates'],feature['properties']['address']+'\n') TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

как правильно написать чтобы сохраняло без ошибок

Comment: У вас неправильные аргументы `feature['geometry']['coordinates'],feature['properties']['address']+'\n'` получается 2 аргумента, а на запись надо впихнуть их в один. Объедините например в список и передайте его первым аргументом.

Comment: @S. Nick отреагировал спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас свежая версия питона, то просто используйте f-строки:

```
f.write(f"{feature['geometry']['coordinates']}, {feature['properties']['address']}\n")
```

Кроме того, лучше открывать файл, используя конструкцию `with`, чтобы не нужно было помнить о закрытии файла - он закроется сам по окончании вложенного блока кода. Итого:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://5ka.ru/api/stores/?bbox=10.0000,10.0000,100.0000,100.0000')
if r.status_code == 200:
    j = json.loads(r.text[9:-2]) # обрезаем лишнее обрамление у JSON
    with open(r'D:\Arcgis\M.txt','w'):
        for feature in j['data']['features']:
            f.write(f"{feature['geometry']['coordinates']}, {feature['properties']['address']}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
f=open(r'D:\Arcgis\M.txt','w')
r = requests.get('https://5ka.ru/api/stores/?bbox=10.0000,10.0000,100.0000,100.0000')
if r.status_code == 200:
    j = json.loads(r.text[9:-2]) # обрезаем лишнее обрамление у JSON
    for feature in j['data']['features']:
        f.write((f"{feature['geometry']['coordinates']}, {feature['properties']['address']}\n").replace('[','').replace(']',''))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Не экономьте буквы на названиях переменных )  Понятно, что не вы это начали, но `f` для `file` это просто уже конвенциональное сокращение, которое все поймут, а вот `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` - так можно для математических вычислений, но не для объектов.

Comment: @CrazyElf  для меня гуманитария это все как темный лес так что спасибо за подсказку